# Error building SCP command syntax in read loop

Tags: bash, scp

I'm trying to get a list of files copied by SCP from one server to another but the command seems not to be getting build correctly in the `read` loop.

I have a file called `diff_tapes.txt` which contains a list of files to be copied as follows:

```
/VAULT14/TEST_V14/634001
/VAULT14/TEST_V14/634002
/VAULT14/TEST_V14/634003
/VAULT14/TEST_V14/634004
```

etc etc...

The bash command line I'm using is as follows:

```
while read line; do scp -p bill@lgrdcpvtsa:$line $line;done < /home/bill/diff_tapes.txt
```

When I execute that from the command line (I'm running on CentOS so basically Red Hat) I get:

```
/VAULT14/TEST_V14/634001: No such file or directory
```

... for every single file.

If I run again adding the `-v` switch to get more info, I see the following:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -p -f /VAULT14/TEST_V14/634001
```

The remote server (lgrdcpvtsa) definitely has the files in question:

```
[bill@LGRDCPVTSA TEST_V14]$ pwd
/VAULT14/TEST_V14
[bill@LGRDCPVTSA TEST_V14]$ ls -ll
total 207200
-rw------- 1 bill bill 27263700 Apr 26 11:16 634001
-rw------- 1 bill bill 27263700 Apr 26 11:16 634002
-rw------- 1 bill bill 27263700 Apr 26 11:16 634003
-rw------- 1 bill bill 27263700 Apr 26 11:16 634004
```

It's as though the second time I have `$line` in the scp command, it's ignored.

Any idea what's wrong with the syntax?

**EDIT:**

For clarity, the list of files is more likely to be like this:

```
/VAULT14/634100_V14/634001
/VAULT11/601100_V11/601011
/VAULT12/510200_V12/510192
```

And `/VAULT10` through `/VAULT14` exists on both servers, it's just the next folder node might not.

These files are files flagged as being different on local vs remote machine, hence copying from the remote machine which is the correct data source, so a recursive copy won't work here (I think the `-r` switch was a hangover from an earlier test so I've removed that from the code above).

Comment: Is there no way to create the directory at runtime? If not, I guess I'll need to parse the file list first to pick up directories and create if they are not there locally, and then run this, be nice if I could do it in the one command though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably because the local directory `/VAULT14/TEST_V14/` does not exist.

You can use the `dirname` command to get the directory name from the path, create the directory, and then executing the `scp` command. Example

```
while read line; do mkdir -p "$(dirname "$line")"; scp -rp bill@lgrdcpvtsa:"$line" "$line";done < /home/bill/diff_tapes.txt
```

The `-p` option tells `mkdir` to create the subdirectories even if the parent does not exist.

**EDIT:**
This was copying all the files to `/` so have changed to the following which is working perfectly:

```
while read line; do mkdir -p "$(dirname "$line")"; scp -p bill@lgrdcpvtsa:"$line" "$line";done < /home/bill/diff_tapes.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't come across the `dirname` command before, really useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

> /VAULT14/TEST_V14/634001: No such file or directory

This is likely because the folder  `/VAULT14/TEST_V14/` does not exist on the local machine.

Result:

```
mkdir /VAULT14/TEST14
while read line; do 
    scp -p bill@lgrdcpvtsa:"$line" "$line"
done < /home/bill/diff_tapes.txt
```

Comment: That won't work here, in my example the files are consecutive and in the same directory as each other but running live there are going to be lots of files in format `/VAULT1n/nnnnnn_V1n/nnnnnn` as the file will be a list of files that are not the same on the two servers (either doesn't exist on the local machine or local machine copy is not up to date with the remote copy). This list was produced from diff over ssh (I can't use `rsync` because of it's handling of sparse files, even with `-S` set not being as good as `scp`)

Comment: So why you are using `scp -r` ? Btw, I cannot imagine that rsync will not do the job

Comment: `-r` was a handover from and earlier test, have removed that now.
The problem with `rsync` is that when the files were copied using that, their stated size once copied was wildly incorrect as though they are sparse files (200MB file on the remote machine was reported as 3GB on the local machine and even using `-S` switch it was still inaccurate, just not by as much! It throws off the `df` results which will confuse the operators.

Comment: Updated my command line accordingly (`/VAULT14` itself exists):
`while read line; do scp -p bill@lgrdcpvtsa:"$line" "$line";done < /home/bill/diff_tapes.txt`

Still getting `no such file or directory`

Comment: @GrahamGold Sorry I've been missing to correct this as my former post assumed the usage of `-r`. In this case it would being wrong to create `TEST14`. Updated it